# QML- How to use Multiple data models for ListViews in QML

Tags: qml

I want to use 2 models in 2 List Views, but the 2nd list is not populated like the first one.
The code that I have used as follows:

```
Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));
  MyModel myModel;
  myModel.addPrimaryData(ModelItem(1, "Apple"));
  myModel.addPrimaryData(ModelItem(2, "Orange"));
  myModel.addPrimaryData(ModelItem(3, "Banana"));

  MyModel myModel2;
  myModel2.addSecondaryData(ModelItem(1, "Apple2"));
  myModel2.addSecondaryData(ModelItem(2, "Orange2"));
  myModel2.addSecondaryData(ModelItem(3, "Banana2"));

  QDeclarativeView declView;
  QDeclarativeContext *declContext = declView.rootContext();
  declContext->setContextProperty("myModel", &myModel);
  declContext->setContextProperty("myModel2", &myModel2);

  declView.setSource(QUrl("qml/MyDemo/main.qml"));
  declView.show();

  return app->exec();
}
```

As displayed above, I have created 2 models i.e myModel and myModel2 and Used in 2 Listy Views in QML.

ListView1 uses model myModel  and ListView2 uses model myModel2. But myModel2 data are not displaying in the list.

Any specific reasons for this. Please reply with your thoughts.

The QML Code that I have used is as follows:

```
ListView {
   id:firstListView
   model: myModel
   delegate: Item{
   id: firstDelegate
   Text {
     text: name
     color: "white"
   }
 }
}

 ListView {
   id: secondListView
   model: myModel2
   delegate: Item{
   id: secondDelegate
   Text {
      text: name
      color: "white"
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: You should post QML code as well.

Comment: You didn't give any information on the innards of your model nor the way you use them in QML despite the fact that you employ two ListView items. Too much uncertainty to give any educated answer.

Comment: I have updated the post, please revisit and provide your comments.

Comment: Still nothing about the model... I don't see any errors in your QML code.

Comment: please reply to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't given us your `MyModel` implementation, there is very little help we can provide. For now all I can suggest is to check the following:

- Make sure role name for the second model is in fact "name".
- Make sure the second `ListView` isn't just hiding under the first.
- Compare your implementations between `addPrimaryData` and `addSecondaryData` to make sure the code works in both.

You'll have to show us how your `MyModel` works if you want a more specific answer.